# My react native apps now crash on my android device when I press reload. They never used to. Builds from other computers work

Tags: android, adb, react-native, gradlew

I'm have been using my Android phone (SM-J320FN) running Android 5.1.1 to work with my react native apps. But now when I do react-native run-android the app installs but when I press reload the app crashes and gives the 'unfortunately has stopped working' notification. This is while "react-native start" is running and I would have done "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081". The crash also happens for all the other apps I already had installed on the device in debug mode.

I tried to install on a friend's device and it worked fine. It also works on the AVD emulator. This led me to think there was a problem with my device so I hard reset it to clear any data caches that may be causing the problem but I got the same problem even after losing all my precious data.

I then tried to install a build from a different computer and it worked and that makes me think there may be some caching on my computer (Windows 10, JDK1.8.0_121, react-native 0.51) that is causing this. I have tried "gradlew cleanbuildcache" but still no luck.

Comment: what does the crash say? can you debug it? there can be a ton of reasons why it fails.

Comment: Make sure you are installing the exact same versions of each dependency. My guess is that you have something like this in your package.json: `"awesome-package": "^3.0.2"`, remove all those `^` and make sure you have the same versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved it using the information from [Crysfel mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569824/my-react-native-apps-now-crash-on-my-android-device-when-i-press-reload-they-ne/69775340#comment84136245_48569824):

> Make sure you are installing the exact same versions of each dependency. My guess is that you have something like this in your package.json: `"awesome-package": "^3.0.2"`, remove all those `^` and make sure you have the same versions.

I found that there was an error in the console when loading the project, with that I tried to fix it and after that everything was OK!
See if there is any console error or inconsistency.